# Azure AD Connect without local Domain Controller

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-connect

Is it possible to have a local server part of an Azure AD via AD Connect without a local DC?

The 3rd party IT of my client claims there is no way, and Microsoft AD Connect pages do not mention that the server must be part of a local DC prior or after the migration/attachment, not sure about the terminology. Their desktops base is already managed in Azure via a VPN and all their servers are in Azure. Cannot tell why this one server is not also moved to Azure (cost of hardware?)

I am genuinely confused and don't know what to say since I have not worked with AD Connect before.

Is that true? is there a Microsoft documentation that clearly specify you need a local DC for AD Connect to work?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum requirement is to have Active directory locally as well because when you sync-up with Azure AD, it syncs up your local AD accounts with their attributes.

There is a lab for test AD connect, let me know if you need it